# What is alternative to NSStatusItem.popUpMenu?

Tags: cocoa, popupmenu, nsstatusitem, macos-mojave

`NSStatusItem.popUpMenu` has been deprecated in macOS 10.14, but I can't find a nice alternative.

```
let m = statusItem.menu!
statusItem.popUpMenu(m) // deprecated
```

I tried direct pop-up using menu and the button, but it doesn't position properly.

```
let m1 = m.items.first!
m.popUp(positioning: m1, at: .zero, in: statusItem.button!)
```

Answer (score 14):

Xcode suggests to use `menu` property instead of `popupMenu`. But once you set the `menu` property, every click on the item will only show the menu.

Instead, if you want to control when the menu is shown, say only in response to a right click, then a simple way to manually trigger the menu is by calling `performClick` on `NSStatusBarButton` in your handler.

```swift
statusItem.menu = myMenu
statusItem.button?.performClick(nil)
statusItem.menu = nil
```

You have to set `menu` back to nil, if you want to keep handling clicks yourself.

Comment: Although it hurts this is a great solution 